# Why is Date Picker background color change not visible when running?

Tags: ios, xcode, datepicker

I can change the color of the background on the Date Picker wheel and it is visible in the Storyboard but when I Run it on an iOS device or the simulator no change is present. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong ?

[story board vs. simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDVyy.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set background color via code, for example:

```
datePicker.backgroundColor = .green
```

Comment: What are the possible color variations? I'm  new to this... so do I just enter .green .blue .red ? Or do I have to declare rgb values somehow ?

Comment: Of course you can! Just use `UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha:)` initializer for adding any color with RGB values

Comment: Something like...myColor = UIColor(red:4green:12:alpha:0)     datePicker.backgroundColor= myColor

Comment: You forgot blue component: `UIColor(red: 4, green: 12, blue: 6, alpha: 0)`

Comment: would this be ok ?datePicker.backgroundColor = myColor

Comment: Yes, you can save color in `let` or `var` or see directly like `datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha:)`

Comment: Ok fantastic I will try it when I get home. Thank you will let you know.

Comment: It works! the only trouble is that it works after I pick a data and tap the go button. So basically it turns blue after a date is chosen. I also need it to be blue as soon as the app launches without any interaction.

Comment: Where you set the color? In `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: No that was the problem I had it in the view controller code. I moved it into the viewDidLoad and that fixed it! Thank you.